# What does the T stand for in AXI4-Stream's TDATA, TVALID, TREADY, etc.?

Tags: terminology, axi4

In the [AXI4-Stream](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0051/a/IHI0051A_amba4_axi4_stream_v1_0_protocol_spec.pdf) protocol, the names of the signal that make up a stream are prefixed with `T`: `TDATA`, `TVALID`, `TREADY`, `TLAST`, etc.

Does the `T` prefix have a meaning? "Transfer" comes to mind, but that term is also used in the (non-stream) AXI4 protocol, where the signal names are not prefixed with `T`.

Comment: I would consider these just names, without caring much what the defining guy was drinking or smoking that day. It is a reasonable assumption that it is standing for "transfer" though.

Comment: My guess is the 'S' was already used a lot for AXI slave interfaces (compared to 'M' for master) so they took the next character of 'Stream'. But I have some buddies in Cambridge who regularly see the ARM guys in the pub so maybe after a few drinks they can find out for you, if you pay the beer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear to mean 'Transfer'.

The specification does not explicitly state it but it clearly implies it on p1-2, the second page of the spec':

```
STREAM TERMS

The following stream terms are used in this specification:

TRANSFER  A single transfer of data across an AXI4-Stream interface.
          A single transfer is defined by a single TVALID, TREADY handshake.
          See Handshake process on page 2-3.
```

The definition of a transfer is that it uses a TVALID/TREADY handshake. So a Transfer is that 'T' being made Valid and accepted by Ready. According to that definition text.